# I am accessing DB using ormlite every 5 seconds and if I stay on the same page for long I get this cursor error

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I am accessing database every 5 seconds and if I stay on the same page for long I get this error. I don't know how to fix this. I searched a lot but didn't find a solution yet.

Here is the code in DbHelper(i.e. at dbca.android.myapp.Database.DBHelper.getGlobalData(DBHelper.java:165))

```
 public ArrayList<TableGlobalDatat> getGlobalData() {
        ArrayList<TableGlobalDatat> globalDataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            globalDatatArrayList = (ArrayList<TableGlobalDatat>) getGlobalDataDao().queryForAll();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return globalDatatArrayList;
    }
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed.
at android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:104)
at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:154)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:148)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:197)
at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:237)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.getCursor(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:194)
at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidCompiledStatement.runQuery(AndroidCompiledStatement.java:72)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.(SelectIterator.java:57)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:247)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:197)
at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:126)
at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:248)
at dbca.android.myapp.Database.DBHelper.getGlobalData(DBHelper.java:165)
at dbca.android.myapp.network.SyncData.parseMessageList(SyncData.java:456)
at dbca.android.myapp.network.SyncData.access$500(SyncData.java:51)
at dbca.android.myapp.network.SyncData$10.onResponse(SyncData.java:427)
at dbca.android.myapp.network.SyncData$10.onResponse(SyncData.java:424)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:83)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5427)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! - Please post the code pertaining to this error please. `at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)`

Comment: refer this issue already registered in git repo https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/issues/55

Comment: I have added the code where the error shows.

Comment: I have posted my issue on that same page  @Munir as I didn't find a solution there.

Comment: @ OcelotcR do I need to post any more code?